# Active admin CSV export custom query scoped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Am using active admin Export CSV option. Its returning all the values related to the particular table.

I want the reports only for a particular month.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can write own csv exporter

```
collection_action :download_report, :method => :get do
    users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today - 1.month)
      csv = CSV.generate( encoding: 'Windows-1251' ) do |csv|
      # add headers
      csv < [ #Some header ]
      # add data
      users.each do |user|
        csv << [ user.created_at ]
      end      
    end
    # send file to user
    send_data csv.encode('Windows-1251'), type: 'text/csv; charset=windows-1251; header=present', disposition: "attachment; filename=report.csv"
  end

  action_item only: :index do
    link_to('csv report'), params.merge(:action => :download_report))
  end 

  index :download_links => false do
    # off standard download link
  end
```

this is **just example** for you. Your code can be another

Comment: I have added like this only for User table. Actually it was returning all the users list in the CSV. But i want only the users lists created between particular dates. For example I want the users list who are all registred in the last months

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also i dont want this custom query for default index page. I want this only for CSV export option. How to Disable this scoped_collection for normal active admin index action. I mean this scoped_collection should execute only for CSV export option.

Comment: you can write own exporter

Answer (score 1):

for generation csv file use this code where you want

```
# generate csv file of photo
  def self.generate_csv
    header = []
    csv_fname = "#{CSV_FILE_PATH}/images.csv"
    options = {headers: :first_row}
    photo_columns = column_names - ["id", "updated_at"]
    photo_columns.map{|col| col == "created_at" ? header << "ScrapeDate" : header << col.classify}
    CSV.open(csv_fname, "w", options ) do |csv|
      csv << header if File.exist?(csv_fname) && File.size(csv_fname) == 0
      find_each(batch_size: 5000) do |photo|
        csv << photo.attributes.values_at(*photo_columns)
      end
    end
  end
```

in above code which column you don't want subtract that cols from actual cols, for example `column_names - ["id", "updated_at"]` here column_names return actual cols array and which cols we don't need we subtract them.

Comment: I dont want this CSV generation. Only thing i want is How to customize active admin Export CSV option. Actually its returning all the values form the table. I want data monthly basis.

Comment: this is internal method of active admin or this is created by some one or you.